# Delphi IBTable readonly error

Tags: delphi, interbase, delphi-xe3

I just installed the latest version of `Embarcadero Delphi XE3`. I made a simple form connecting to `InterBase` Database. I have `IBDatabase`, `IBTable`, `IBTransaction`, `Grid` and some other components. Everything works fine and it shows data in the grid. But I want to be able to edit this data. So at the `IBTable` component I set the `ReadOnly` property to false and every time I do this the program stops working and I get this:

`Dynamic SQL Error 
SQL error code = - 206 
Column unknown 
IBTable1`

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to use IBTable component. Usage of IBDataset or IBQuery is advised. [Read this](https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=500088&ei=pWh-UMrXC9G6hAecwYGICw&usg=AFQjCNFz64wYFVxzfTDoPW_AE_aJ62SxMQ)

Comment: So what should I use to link IBDatabase with a grid?

Comment: @Ertunç, where did you find the information it will be discontinued ? Embarcadero would mark [`the class`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/IBTable.TIBTable) as deprecated if they would going to do so.

Comment: @TLama "New project should not be using it." in the link. I think I misunderstood this. Sorry for that. But it is still not recommended by TeamB. Read the link please.

Comment: @Ertunç, no need to excuse :-) Just correct your answer that it's not recommended to use it by one guy from TeamB, suggest the alternative, fix the link so that it won't go through Google and delete your comment from here (like I'll do with both my comments in few seconds).

Comment: You are advised to use ... " IBDataset is the best, followed by IBQuery (read only without a TINUpdateObject
attached). Just set their SQL, attach it to the grid and open it exactly like
you would the IBTable, the only difference is you are writing SQL. "

Comment: I repaced IBTable with IBDataset. The result is the same - I can see the data but I don't see a way to edit it.

Comment: OK, I finally managed to edit data in an Edit component not in the grid. And I write some SQL commands in IBDataset. I expected to be easier but anyway - it works.

Comment: You should click the accept sign on left of the answer to set it as fixed